# how to define submodule in package.json to make 'require('module/submodule')'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, require, package.json

I have a library of components, that have to be compiled.
I compile my sources to `dist` folder with a file `index.js` (and all other compiled files) which exports all components like this

```
/*index.js*/
module.exports = {
"component1": require('./components/component1/component1'),
"component2": require('./components/component2/component2')
}
```

I have this setting in my `package.json` file
    "main": "./dist",

so, I can require this library like this `require('library')`

**Problem:** I also want to export my components one-by-one to make it possible to require them partially like `require('library/component1')`

I could put for instance, `component1.js` file in `./dist` folder with further require, but it still makes me write `require('library/dist/component1')`

**Quistion:** Is it possible to make it somehow staying files inside of 'dist' folder?

Comment: can't you settle for `require('library').component1` ? (which already works in your case)

Comment: No. In this case the whole library will be loaded. 

The goal is to load only one part